# Creating a list of RSS items with select menu

Tags: drupal-7, rss, aggregator

I'm a Drupal novice. I need to show a list of 4 RSS feed items with a select menu above to change the feed and have the list update (via ajax). I've investigated the Views module a bit but I can't tell if it's what I need. Can someone point me in the right direction? Should I just try to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [views module](https://drupal.org/project/views) .

Since you are new to Drupal, try [this series of tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3L9JLZOb_LQ) this should help you up and running with views in no time.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how to use the Views Module to do this. Took some fiddling but it worked!